# Reversing Arrays, Array.Reverse()

Tags: c#

I have the following code to reverse a string:

```
Console.Title = "*****Reverse a String*****";
Console.WriteLine("*****Reverse a String*****");
Console.WriteLine("=> Enter the text to be reversed:");
string input = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("=> Reversing...");
char[] arrInput = input.ToCharArray();
Array.Reverse(arrInput);
String final = new String(arrInput);
Console.WriteLine("=> {0}", final);
Console.WriteLine("=> Press any key to terminate.");
Console.ReadKey();
```

Array.Reverse(arrInput) works but arrInput.Reverse() doesnt! Any pointers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`arrInput.Reverse` uses LINQ `Reverse` method which doesn't change the original collection. You need to call `ToArray` on it

```
var reversed = arrInput.Reverse().ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks! Will select as answer when it lets me!

Answer (score 1):

arrInput.Reverse() returns an enumerable:

```
IEnumerable<char> inputEnumerable = arrInput.Reverse();
```

Also as Selman22 points out, `Reverse()` is going to return an IEnumerable not an array, so you'll also have to add `ToArray()` if you want to use the original variable:

```
arrInput = arrInput.Reverse().ToArray();
```

Comment: @Selman22 Good point, I was thinking the array could hold an IEnumerable for some reason

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to explicitly create an array to use the `Reverse` method; you could just do this:

```
// Get string from user as you're already doing
string input = Console.ReadLine();

// Reverse it and assign to new string
string reversed = new string(input.Reverse().ToArray());
```

In other words, this code:

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("=> Reversing...");
char[] arrInput = input.ToCharArray();
Array.Reverse(arrInput);
String final = new String(arrInput);
```

Can be simplified to:

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("=> Reversing...");
String final = new String(input.Reverse().ToArray());
```

Comment: Wouldn't .ToArray() make it an array which would make it an array when reversed is a string?

Comment: @LukeParker Not really; `Reverse` is called first, which returns an IEnumerable<char>. The ToArray() call is needed to convert the `IEnumerable` to an `Array` type for the `string` constructor. But you can call `Reverse` on a string without converting it to an Array, like: `var reversed = "some String".Reverse();`. Just as you can grab a character from a string using an index without explicitly converting it to an array: `char fourthCharacter = "someString"[3];`

Comment: Updated answer with how the explicit array declaration can be removed, hope that helps.